# In power query, how to turn a number into a duration in seconds?

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying, in power BI, to create change the type of one of my columns. Said column contain Numbers and I am trying to turn that number into a duration in seconds. But whenever I use the default type change, it turn the duration into days.

`= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type",{{"Duration", type duration}})`

is the default, I've tried puttin duration(seconds) or duration.seconds, but it didn't work.
I've looked around for a solution, but all I get are DAX solutions. I couldn't find much about power query in general.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I think you could add a new column from examples, and multiply your cell number by the corresponding value (ex: from hours to seconds: column * 3600). It'll do that for every row. Then just delete your unwanted old column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this does what you want.

If you start with a column called Seconds:

[image]

You can add a column with `= Duration.From([Seconds]/86400)` to get:

[image]

Alternatively, you could use:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(Source, each [Seconds],each Duration.From([Seconds]/86400),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Seconds"})
```

to change...

[image]

directly to...

[image]

Here's the M code for the two different options:

Adding a column:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Duration", each Duration.From([Seconds]/86400))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Directly changing:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source, each [Seconds],each Duration.From([Seconds]/86400),Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Seconds"})
in
    #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Now I regret trying to work with durations :p I thought it would make it easier to do show in different formats (minutes/hours) afterward. God was I wrong. I don't even understand how it shows it in tables.
Regardless, I got what I asked for. Thanks

Comment: @Elgate, you might check out [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/duration-functions).